# The "blub paradox" and c++

Tags: c++, programming-languages

I was reading the article here: http://www.paulgraham.com/avg.html and the part about the "blub paradox" was particularly interesting. As someone who mainly codes in c++ but has exposure to other languages (mostly Haskell) I'm aware of a few useful things in these languages that are hard to replicate in c++. The question is mainly to people who are proficient in both c++ and some other language, is there some powerful language feature or idiom that you make use of in a language that would be hard to conceptualize or implement if you were writing only in c++?

In particular this quote caught my attention:

> By induction, the only programmers in
>   a position to see all the differences
>   in power between the various languages
>   are those who understand the most
>   powerful one. (This is probably what
>   Eric Raymond meant about Lisp making
>   you a better programmer.) You can't
>   trust the opinions of the others,
>   because of the Blub paradox: they're
>   satisfied with whatever language they
>   happen to use, because it dictates the
>   way they think about programs.

If it turns out that I am the equivalent of the "Blub" programmer by virtue of using c++ this raises the following question: Are there any useful concepts or techniques that you have encountered in other languages that you would have found difficult to conceptualize had you been writing or "thinking" in c++?

For example the logic programming paradigm seen in languages like Prolog and Mercury can be implemented in c++ using the castor library but ultimately I find that conceptually I am thinking in terms of Prolog code and translating to the c++ equivalent when using this. As a way of broadening my programming knowledge I'm trying to find out if there are other similar examples of useful/powerful idioms that are more efficiently expressed in other languages that I might not be aware of as a c++ developer. Another example that comes to mind is the macro system in lisp, generating the program code from within the program seems to have many benefits for some problems. This seems to be hard to implement and think about from within c++.

This question is not intended to be a "c++ vs lisp" debate or any sort of language-wars type debate. Asking a question like this is the only way I can see possible to find out about things that I don't know I don't know about.

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_relativity

Comment: I agree.  So long as this doesn't turn into a C++ vs Lisp debate I think there is something to be learned here.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: `there are things that other languages can do that Lisp can't` -- Unlikely, since Lisp is Turing-complete.  Perhaps you meant to say that there are some things that are not *practical* to do in Lisp?  I could say the same thing about *any* programming language.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: "All languages are equally powerful in the sense of being Turing equivalent, but that's not the sense of the word programmers care about. (No one wants to program a Turing machine.) The kind of power programmers care about may not be formally definable, but one way to explain it would be to say that it refers to features you could only get in the less powerful language by writing an interpreter for the more powerful language in it." -- Paul Graham, in a footnote to the trollpost in question.  (See what I mean?)

Comment: @Mason Wheeler: (Not really.)

Comment: @RobertHarvey My objection to the concept is that it's all too easy to use his very own words to show that he's the one suffering from the blub paradox, and that the argument has no real value because it can be used, practically unchanged, to support any position, to demonstrate that any language is actually "less powerful than" [insert language of choice here].

Answer (score 17):

Well, since you mentioned Haskell:

1. Pattern Matching. I find pattern matching to be much easier to read and write. Consider the definition of map and think about how it would be implemented in a language without pattern matching.

   ```
   map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
   map f [] = []
   map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
   ```
2. The type system. It can be a pain sometimes but it is extremely helpful. You have to program with it to really understand it and how many bugs it catches. Also, referential transparency is wonderful. It only becomes apparent after programming in Haskell for a while how many bugs are caused by managing state in an imperative language.
3. Functional programming in general. Using maps and folds instead of iteration. Recursion. It's about thinking at a higher level.
4. Lazy evaluation. Again it's about thinking at a higher level and letting the system handle evaluation.
5. Cabal, packages, and modules. Having Cabal download packages for me is much more convenient than finding source code, writing a makefile, etc. Being able to import only certain names is much better than essentially having all the source files dumped together then compiled.

Comment: A note on pattern matching: I wouldnt say its easier to write in general, but after you read a bit on the expression problem it becomes clear that things like if and switch statements, enums and the observer pattern are all inferior implementations of Algebraic Data Types + Pattern Matching. (And lets not even get started on how Maybe makes null pointer exceptions obsolete)

Comment: What you say is true, but the expression problem is about limitations of algebraic data types (and about the dual limitations of standard OOP).

Comment: @hugomg Did you mean Visitor pattern instead of Observer?

Comment: yes. I always switch those two names :)

Comment: @hugomg It's not about having `Maybe` (for C++ see [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)), it's about having to explicitly mark things as optional / nullable / maybe.

Answer (score 7):

### [Memoize!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)

Try writing it in C++. **Not** with C++0x.

Too cumbersome? Okay, try it *with* C++0x.

See if you can beat this 4-line (or 5-line, whatever :P) *compile-time* version in D:

```
auto memoize(alias Fn, T...)(T args) {
    auto key = tuple(args);                               //Key is all the args
    static typeof(Fn(args))[typeof(key)] cache;           //Hashtable!
    return key in cache ? cache[key] : (cache[key] = Fn(args));
}
```

All you need to do for calling it is something like:

```
int fib(int n) { return n > 1 ? memoize!(fib)(n - 1) + memoize!(fib)(n - 2) : 1;}
fib(60);
```

---

You can also try something similar in Scheme, although it's a bit slower because it happens at run time and because the lookup here is linear instead of hashed (and well, because it's Scheme):

```
(define (memoize f)
    (let ((table (list)))
        (lambda args
            (cdr
                (or (assoc args table)
                    (let ((entry (cons args (apply f args))))
                        (set! table (cons entry table))
                        entry))))))
(define (fib n)
        (if (<= n 1)
            1
            (+ (fib (1- n))
                (fib (- n 2)))))))
(set! fib (memoize fib))
```

Comment: So you love APL where you can write anything in a single line? Size doesn't matter!

Comment: @Bo: I haven't used APL. I'm not sure what you mean by "size doesn't matter", but is there something wrong with my code that makes you say that? And is there some advantage to how you would do this in a different language (like C++) that I'm not aware of? (I edited the variable names a bit, in case that was what you were referring to.)

Comment: @Mehrdad - My comment is about the most compact program isn't a sign of the best programming language. In that case [APL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language)#Examples) would win hands down, because you do most things with a single char operator. Only problem is that it is unreadable.

Comment: @Bo: Like I said, I wasn't recommending APL; I've never even seen it. Size was *one* criterion (although a significant one, as can be seen if you try this with C++)... but is there anything wrong with *this* code?

Comment: [How I memoized a function in c++](http://mojoai.blogspot.com/2010/05/memoizing-functions-in-c.html)

Comment: @Matt: Your code memoized *a* function, but this code can memoize *any* function. These aren't really equivalent at all. If you actually try writing a higher-order function like this in C++0x, it's a lot more tedious than in D (although it's still quite possible... though it's not possible in C++03).

Comment: I bet it could be possible in c++03 if you used c++ macros. I don't use c++ a lot, so I'm not going to attempt it, but it doesn't seem implausible.

Comment: @Matt: It's *impossible* because you need variadic templates, which don't exist in C++03.

Comment: @Mehrdad - Perhaps we have shown that the blub paradox is true? :-) You use a hashtable, because there is one. Otherwise we could do compile time Fibonacci with templates in both D and C++.

Comment: um, what about printf? That is a variadic function in c++0stoneage, so then it is possible?

Comment: @Bo: I wasn't referring to compile-time Fibonacci, but compile-time *memoization*. The Fibonacci happens at *run-time*, but the point here is that there's no overhead associated with calling memoize() because it's done at compile-time. I wasn't trying to show the compile-time features, but the ability to do template metaprogramming in ways that are much less trivial (if not impossible) in C++.

Comment: @Matt: That would lose type safety and would introduce potential segfaults. Not to mention that it's slower because of the run-time overhead.

Comment: Anyway, my point is not that it's possible using c++ templates, but that it is possible to write a way to memoise any function in c++.

Comment: @Merhdad - Yes, and the blub paradox says that the way we create a solution is influenced by the tool we use. :-)

Comment: @Bo: That's completely true, what you use affects how you think. But I do have to say that I knew C++ and C# before learning Scheme and D, so it's not like I was going with a biased opinion to start with. ;) This was just meant to be an example of something that you can do trivially in some languages but not others.

Comment: What does "compile time memoization" mean in this context? Do you mean that the memoization logic isn't added through a higher order function? Because that's entirely possible in scheme via macros, and using a hashtable is possible in scheme too via SRFI libraries.

Comment: @Jack: It's been 5 years since my comment so my memory has faded, but what I think I was saying was that in the D version, all the memoization code is generated at compile time, whereas in Scheme, I'm not sure that's the case, even with macros. (It may be, I'm not familiar with it enough to be sure but it seems like it might not be.) For example, if I call `(lambda () (memoize fib))`, repeatedly, how many times is `(memoize fib)` called?

Comment: @Mehrdad - Scheme macros exist entirely for the purpose of generating code at compile time. The scheme macro version would look something like `(define/memoize (fib n) fib-body ...)` and wouldn't use a higher order function.

Comment: @Jack: I'm not clear on what exactly you are saying. Are you saying that if `memoize` is a macro, then `(memoize fib)` is evaluated if I write `(lambda () (memoize fib))`? (Note that `memoize` certainly wouldn't be called if it was a function, since it's in a lambda. Would it behave differently as a macro?)

Comment: `memoize` would still be a higher order function, but the macro forms would be `lambda/memoize` and `define/memoize`. In a hypothetical Racket implementation, the expression `(lambda/memoize (a b c) (+ a b c))` would be macro-expanded to `(let ([table (make-hash)]) (lambda (a b c) (hash-ref! table (list a b c) (lambda () (+ a b c)))))` and `define/memoize` would be a simple wrapper around `lambda/memoize`. All memoization code is generated at compile time, with no runtime overhead from a higher order function.

Comment: @Jack: I don't understand why you're avoiding answering the question I'm asking you. The entire point of my question is that I'm putting the macro invocation inside a lambda that is never invoked, and asking you what the result is. You keep ignoring my question and then giving me an answer to another question that I'm not asking, which isn't helpful.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I don't understand the question then. You are correct that your example will not work in scheme. But your example isn't a macro, and it's also not how a macro approach to memoization would be designed in the first place. The "macro invocation" wouldn't be *inside* a lambda, it would *create* a lambda.

Comment: @Jack: What I'm trying to get across to you (and apparently failing here) is that, as far as I know, Scheme macros do not actually get expanded at "compile" time (or perhaps I should say "parse" time); they get expanded at run time. If they got expanded at compile time, my example would work. Contrast it with the D version, where `memoize!(fib)` is *inside* the `fib` function definition... in that case, `memoize` is invoked (and the code is all generated at compile time) even if `fib` is never invoked. I hope you see it now because I don't know how else to explain it.

Comment: That's precisely my point, Scheme macros **do** get expanded at compile/parse time. There is a macro expansion step during compilation where this happens. They can be expanded at runtime too because scheme has `eval`, but "normal" macros expand during compilation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39992/discussion-between-mehrdad-and-jack).

Answer (score 5):

C++ is a multiparadigm language, which means it tries to support many ways of thinking. Sometimes a C++ feature is more awkward or less fluent than another language's implementation, as is the case with functional programming.

That said, I can't think off the top of my head of a native C++ language feature that does what **`yield`** in Python or JavaScript does.

Another example is **concurrent programming**. C++0x will have a say about it, but the current standard doesn't, and concurrency is a whole new way of thinking.

Also, rapid development -- even shell programming -- is something you'll never learn if you never leave the domain of C++ programming.

Comment: I can't even begin to think how difficult it would be to create generators in C++ given C++2003. C++2011 would make it easier, but still non-trivial.  Working routinely with C++, C# and Python, generators are easily the easily the feature I miss the most in C++ (now that C++2011 has added lambdas).

Comment: I know I'll get shot for this, but if I *absolutely had to* implement generators in C++, I'd have to use ... `setjmp` and `longjmp`. I have no idea how much that breaks, but I guess exceptions would be the first to go. Now, if you'll excuse me, I need to go reread *Modern C++ Design* to get that out of my head.

Comment: @Mike DeSimone, can you elaborate (breifly) on how  you'd attempt a solution with setjmp and longjmp?

Comment: `*gets out his rifle*` - `*aims at @Mike*` - `*BANG*`

Comment: @Xeo, @Mike: http://xkcd.com/292

Comment: @Mehrdad: xkcd ftw. :)

Comment: @shuttle: First, you'd have to define some kind of generator class, with at least a forward iterator API. Initially, it would `setjmp(a)` where it was and call the generating function (a virtual method of the generator?). When that function called yield, the yielded value would be stored in the object, then `setjmp(b)` and `longjmp(a, 1)` would be used to save the spot and return to the original caller, which would return the yielded value. When called again to get the next value, it would `longjmp(b, 1)` to get back where it was. When the generator function exits, it calls `longjmp(a, 2)`.

Comment: @shuttle: (continued) The thing is, I don't know if the `jmp_buf`s are even *valid* after a `return`. Or how to pass an exception out of the generator function up to the caller. @Xeo: `*THUD*` durr... @Mehrdad: `import antigravity`. In my defense, I'd like to point out that even though `goto` is considered harmful, it is the basis upon which `if`, `while`, and `switch` are based. `switch`'s nasty fall-through effects are entirely because it's really just a table-lookup `goto`.

Comment: @Mike: `setjmp` and `longjmp` utterly break quite a lot of things in C++, unfortunately. I've looked into this sort of thing. Of course, I'd wager there are a number of ways to implement generators/coroutines in C++, some more sane than others.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone - your thoughts about the validity of `jmp_buf` after a return are valid.  Specifically, in the scheme you describe, calling `longjmp(a, 1)` will make the `b` buffer invalid.   There isn't any way of achieving this in standard C/C++, but if you're willing to mess around with stacks you can achieve it, but it's very compiler/hardware dependent, and may well amount to writing a (simple) operating system.  You probably just want to use threads and queues and be done with it...

Answer (score 5):

[Coroutines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine) are an immensely useful language feature that underpin a lot of the more tangible benefits of other languages over C++.  They basically provide extra stacks so functions can be interrupted and continued, providing pipeline-like facilities to the language that easily feed the results of operations through filters to other operations.  It's wonderful, and in Ruby I found it very intuitive and elegant.  Lazy evaluation ties in to this as well.

Introspection and run-time code compilation/execution/evaluation/whatever are massively powerful features that C++ lacks.

Comment: Coroutines are available in FreeRTOS ([see here](http://www.freertos.org/index.html?http://www.freertos.org/croutine.html)), which is implemented in C. I wonder what it would take to make them work in C++?

Comment: Co-routines are a nasty hack to emulate objects in C. In C++, objects are used to bundle code and data. But in C, you can't. So you use the co-routine stack to store the data, and the co-routine function to hold the code.

Comment: Coroutines in C++: http://www.crystalclearsoftware.com/soc/coroutine/

Comment: @Ferruccio: Thanks for the link... there are a few in the Wikipedia article too.  @MSalters: what makes you describe co-routines as "a nasty hack"?  Seems a very arbitrary perspective to me.  Using a stack to store state also done by recursive algorithms - are they hackish too?  FWIW, coroutines and OOP came on the scene about the same time (early 1960s)... to say the former's a hack for objects in C seems bizarre... I'd imagine few C programmers back then were interested in emulating objects, >15 years before C++.

Answer (score 4):

Having implemented a computer algebra system in both Lisp and C++, I can tell you that the task was much easier in Lisp, even though I was a complete novice to the language.  This simplistic nature of everything being lists simplifies a great many algorithms.  Granted, the C++ version was zillions of times faster.  Yeah, I could've made the lisp version faster, but the code wouldn't be as lispy.  Scripting is another thing that is always going to be easier is lisp, for example.  It's all about using the right tool for the job.

Comment: What was the difference in speed?

Comment: @quant_dev: a multiple of a zillion, of course!

Comment: I never really measured it but I had a feeling the big O's were different.  I originally wrote the C++ version in a functional style and it had speed problems also until I taught it to modify the data structures instead of creating new, changed ones.  But that also made the code harder to read...

Answer (score 3):

### Associative Arrays

A typical way of processing data is:

- reading the input and construct a hierarchical structure from it,
- creating indexes for that structure (e.g. different order),
- creating extracts (filtered parts) of them,
- finding a value or a group of value (node),
- re-arrange the structure (delete nodes, add, append, remove sub-elements based on a rule etc.),
- scan thru the tree and print out or save some parts of them.

The right tool for it is **associative array**.

- The best language support for associative arrays I've seen is **MUMPS**, where associative arrays are: 1. always sorted 2. they can be created on disk (so-called database), with the very same syntax. (Side effect: it's extremly powerful as database, the programmer has access to the native btree. Best NoSQL system ever.)
- My second prize goes to **PHP**, I like *foreach* and easy syntax, like *$a[] = x* or *$a[x][y][z]++*.

I don't really like JavaScript's associative array syntax, because I can't create, say *a[x][y][z] = 8*, first I have to create *a[x]* and *a[x][y]*.

Okay, in C++ (and in Java) there are nice portfolio of container classes, *Map*, *Multimap*, whatsoever, but if I wanna scan through, I have to make an iterator, and when I wanna insert a new deep-level element, I have to create all the upper levels etc. Uncomfortable.

I don't say that there're no usable associative arrays in C++ (and Java), but typeless (or non-strict typed) script languages beats compiled ones, because they're typeless script languages.

*Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with C# and other .NET languges, AFAIK they have good associative array handling.*

Comment: Full disclosure: [MUMPS](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/A_Case_of_the_MUMPS.aspx) [is not](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Avoiding-MUMPS--Arcadius.aspx) [for](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/MUMPS-Madness.aspx) [everyone.](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Revenge-of-MUMPS-Madness!.aspx) Quote: *To give a little more “real world” example of the horror that is MUMPS, start by taking one part International Obfuscated C Code Contest, a dash of Perl, two heaping measures of FORTRAN and SNOBOL, and the independent and uncoordinated contributions of dozens of medical researchers, and there you go.*

Comment: In Python, you can use either the built-in `dict` type (e.g. `x = {0: 5, 1: "foo", None: 500e3}`, note that there is no requirement for keys or values to be the same type). Trying to do something like `a[x][y][z] = 8` is hard because the language has to look into the future to see if you're going to set a value or create another level; the expression `a[x][y]` by itself doesn't tell you.

Comment: MUMPS is originally a Basic-like language with associative arrays (may directly stored on the disk!). Later versions contain procedural extensions, which makes it very similar to core PHP. One afraid of Basic and PHP should find Mumps frightening, but others don't. Programmers don't. And remember, it's a very old system, all strange things, like one-letter instructions (altough, you may use full names), L-R evaluation order etc. - as well as non-strange solutions - have only one goal: **optimization**.

Comment: "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%." -- *Donald Knuth.* What you describe sounds to me like a legacy language whose emphasis is backward compatibility, and that's okay. Personally, in those applications, I consider maintainability more important than optimization, and a language with non-algebraic expressions and one-letter commands sounds counterproductive. I serve the customer, not the language.

Comment: @Mike: very entertaining links you posted, I had a good laugh while reading them.

Comment: There's only one math difference from the usual: MUMPS evaluates expressions left-to-right order, e.g. *3+4x4* results 7x4=28. That looks lame, but we have unlimited free brackets, we should use them. The one-letter abbrevation is not mandatory. You can use full function names, altough, some of them begins with letter "Z", e.g. ZSAVE or ZLOAD, ohh. Once I've written a short prg with *full names*, and surprisingly, everyone said, that it is *confusing*, it's harder to read than one-letter style. The readibility does not depends on word lenght, rather depends on *"naturality" of expression*.

Comment: Operator precedence is something people (i.e. new developers) learn in math class, so discarding it to make the MUMPS interpreter easier to write seems like a way to *create* bugs where none were before. And, yes, full names will look weird to developers who have been using abbreviated forms exclusively. That's not because long names are good or bad, but because the experienced developers have expectations as to what they see. The net result is that it only frustrates new developers. It's not *natural*, it's *arbitrary habit*. Perl has this same issue with variables like `$_`.

Answer (score 2):

What do we mean when we say that one language is "more powerful" than another? When we say that a language is "expressive?" Or "rich?" I *think* we mean that a language gains power when its field of view narrows enough to make it easy and natural to describe a problem -- really a state transition, no? -- that lives within that view. Yet that language is considerably less powerful, less expressive, and less useful when our field of view widens.

The more "powerful" and "expressive" the language, the more limited its use. So maybe "powerful" and "expressive" are the wrong words to use for a tool of narrow utility. Maybe "appropriate" or "abstract" are better words for such things.

I started out in programming by writing a whole bunch of low-level stuff: device drivers with their interrupt routines; embedded programs; operating-system code. The code was intimate with the hardware and I wrote it all in assembly language. We wouldn't say that assembler is in the least abstract, yet it was and is the most powerful and expressive language of them all. I can express any problem in assembly language; it's so powerful that I can do anything I please with any machine.

And all of my later understanding of higher-level language owes everything to my experience with assembler. Everything I learned later was easy because, you see, everything -- no matter how abstract -- must in the end accommodate itself to the  hardware.

You might want to forget about higher and higher levels of abstraction -- that is, narrower and narrower fields of view. You can always pick that up later. It's a snap to learn, a matter of days. You'd be better off, in my opinion, to learn the language of hardware<sup>1</sup>, to get as close as you can to the bone.

---

<sup>1</sup>  Perhaps not quite germane, but `car` and `cdr` take their names from the hardware: the first Lisp ran on a machine that had an actual Decrement Register and an actual Address Register. How 'bout that?

Comment: You find that choice is a double edge sword. We all seek it, but there is a dark side to it and it makes us unhappy. It's better to have a very defined view of the world and defined boundaries that you can operate in. People are very creative creatures, and can do great things with limited tools. So to sum it up, I'm saying its not the programming language but having talent people who can make any language sing!

Comment: "To suggest is to create; to define is to destroy." Thinking you could make life easier with another language feels good, but once you make the jump, then you have to deal with the new language's warts.

Comment: I would say that English is way more powerful and expressive than any programming language, and yet the limits of its usefulness expand every day and its utility is immense. Part of the power and expressiveness comes from being able to communicate at the appropriate level of abstraction *and* the ability to invent new abstraction levels when nedded.

Comment: @Mike then you have to deal with communicating with the previous language within the new one ;)

Answer (score 2):

I learn't Java, C\C++, Assembly, and Java Script. I use C++ to make a living.

Though, I would have to say I like Assembly programming and C programming more. This is inline mostly with Imperative programming.

I know that programming Paradigms are important to categorize data types, and give higher programming abstracted concepts to allow powerful design patters and formalization of code. Though in a sense, each Paradigms is a collection of pattern's and collections to abstract the underlying hardware layer so you don't need to think about the EAX, or IP internally within the machine.

My only problem with this, is it allow's peoples notion and concepts of how the machine work to be turned into Ideology's and ambiguous assertions of what is going on. This bread's all kinds of wonderful abstractions on top of abstracts to some ideology goal of the programmer.

At the end of the day, its better to have a good clear mindset and boundaries of what the CPU is and how computers work under the hood. All the CPU cares about is executing a series of instructions that move data in and out of memory into a register and performs a instruction. It has no concept of data type, or any higher programming concepts. It only moves data around.

It becomes more complex when you add programming paradigms into the mix because our view of the world are all different.

Answer (score 2):

> is there some powerful language feature or idiom that you make use of in a language that would be hard to conceptualize or implement if you were writing only in c++?
>
> Are there any useful concepts or techniques that you have encountered in other languages that you would have found difficult to conceptualize had you been writing or "thinking" in c++?

C++ makes many approaches intractable. I would go so far as to say that most of programming is hard to conceptualize if you limit yourself to C++. Here are some examples of problems that are much more easily solved in ways that C++ makes hard.

### Register allocation and calling conventions

Many people think of C++ as a bare metal low level language but it really isn't. By abstracting away important details of the machine, C++ makes it hard to conceptualize practicalities like register allocation and calling conventions.

To learn about concepts like these I recommend having a go at some assembly language programming and check out [this article about ARM code generation quality](http://flyingfrogblog.blogspot.com/2016/05/arm-code-generation-quality.html).

### Run-time code generation

If you only know C++ then you probably think that templates are the be-all and end-all of metaprogramming. They aren't. In fact, they are an objectively bad tool for metaprogramming. Any program that manipulates another program is a metaprogram, including interpreters, compilers, computer algebra systems and theorem provers. Run-time code generation is a useful feature for this.

I recommend firing up a Scheme implementation and playing with `EVAL` to learn about metacircular evaluation.

### Manipulating trees

Trees are everywhere in programming. In parsing you have abstract syntax trees. In compilers you have IRs that are trees. In graphics and GUI programming you have scene trees.

This ["Ridiculously Simple JSON Parser for C++"](https://github.com/subh83/RSJp-cpp/blob/master/RSJparser.tcc) weighs in at just 484 LOC which is very small for C++. Now compare it with [my own simple JSON parser](https://gist.github.com/jdh30/50741cd6d094004203b1dce019726ebb) which weighs in at just 60 LOC of F#. The difference is primarily because ML's algebraic datatypes and pattern matching (including active patterns) make it vastly easier to manipulate trees.

Check out [red-black trees in OCaml](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2009sp/lectures/lec11.html) too.

### Purely functional data structures

Lack of GC in C++ makes it practically impossible to adopt some useful approaches. Purely functional data structures are one such tool.

For example, check out this [47-line regular expression matcher](http://semantic-domain.blogspot.com/2013/11/antimirov-derivatives-for-regular.html) in OCaml. The brevity is due largely to the extensive use of purely functional data structures. In particular, the use of dictionaries with keys that are sets. That is really hard to do in C++ because the stdlib dictionaries and sets are all mutable but you cannot mutate a dictionary's keys or you break the collection.

Logic programming and undo buffers are other practical examples where purely functional data structures make something that is hard in C++ really easy in other languages.

### Tail calls

Not only does C++ not guarantee tail calls but RAII is fundamentally at odds with it because destructors get in the way of a call in tail position. Tail calls let you make an unbounded number of function calls using only a bounded amount of stack space. This is great for implementing state machines, including extensible state machines and it is a great "get out of jail free" card in many otherwise-awkward circumstances.

For example, check out this [implementation of the 0-1 knapsack problem using continuation-passing style with memoization in F#](https://zbray.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/solving-the-0-1-knapsack-problem-using-continuation-passing-style-with-memoization-in-f/) from the finance industry. When you have tail calls, continuation passing style can be an obvious solution but C++ makes it intractable.

### Concurrency

Another obvious example is concurrent programming. Although this is entirely possible in C++ it is extremely error prone compared to other tools, most notably communicating sequential processes as seen in languages like Erlang, Scala and F#.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but since no one has mentioned it, I'll add list (and now dict) comprehensions. It's easy to write a one-liner in Haskell or Python that solves the Fizz-Buzz problem. Try doing that in C++.

While C++ made massive moves to modernity with C++11, it's a bit of a stretch to call it a "modern" language. C++17 (which hasn't been released yet) is making yet more moves to come up to modern standards, so long as "modern" means "not from the previous millennium".

Even the simplest of comprehensions that one can write in one line in Python (and obeying Guido's 79 character line length limit) become lots and lots of lines of codes when translated to C++, and some of those lines of C++ code are rather convoluted.

Comment: Note well: Most of my programming is in C++. I do like the language.

Comment: I thought the Ranges Proposal was supposed to solve this one? (Not even in C++17 I think)

Comment: "massive moves to modernity": What "modern" features does C++11 provide that were invented in the current millennium?

Comment: @MartinBa - My understanding of the "ranges" proposal is that it's a replacement for iterators that are easier to work with and less error prone.  I've not seen any suggestions that they'd allow anything as interesting as list comprehensions.

Comment: @Giorgio - what features of *any* currently popular language were invented in the current millennium?

Comment: Having thought about it for a while, the only thing I can think of is the async/await syntax in C#, or its predecessor the async monad in F#.  There may have been a similar facility in Haskell implemented around the same time.  AFAICT, while the techniques that would be required to implement that were well known back as far as the early 90s, nobody thought of an interface quite like that until relatively recently.

Comment: @Jules: Exactly, very few, if any at all.

Answer (score 0):

A compiled library calling a callback, which is a user defined member function of a user defined class.

---

This is possible in Objective-C, and it makes user interface programming a breeze. You can tell a button: "Please, call this method for this object when you are pressed", and the button will do so. You are free to use any method name for the callback that you like, it is not frozen in the library code, you have not to inherit from an adapter for it to work, nor does the compiler want to resolve the call at compile time, and, equally important, you can tell two buttons to call two different methods of the same object.

I have not seen a similarly flexible way to define a callback in any other language yet (though I'd be very interested to hear about them!). The closest equivalent in C++ is probably passing a lambda function that performs the required call, which again restricts the library code to be a template.

It is this feature of Objective-C that has taught me to value the ability of a language to pass *any* type of objects/functions/whatever-important-concept-the-language-contains around freely, along with the power to save them to variables. Any point in a language that defines any type of concept, but does not provide a means to store it (or a reference to it) in all the available kinds of variables, is a significant stumbling block, and likely a source of much ugly, duplicated code. Unfortunately, baroque programming languages tend to exhibit a number of these points:

- In C++ you cannot write down the type of a VLA, nor store a pointer to it. This effectively prohibits true multidimensional arrays of dynamic size (which are available in C since C99).
- In C++ you cannot write down the type of a lambda. You can't even typedef it. Thus, there is no way to pass around a lambda, or store a reference to it in an object. Lambda functions can only be passed to templates.
- In Fortran you cannot write down the type of a namelist. There is simply no means to pass a namelist to any kind of routine. So, if you have a complex algorithm that should be able to handle two different namelists, you are out of luck. You can't just write the algorithm once and pass the relevant namelists to it.

These are just a few examples, but you see the common point: Whenever you see such a restriction for the first time, you usually won't care because it seems such a crazy idea to do the forbidden thing. However, when you do some earnest programming in that language, you eventually come to the point where this precise restriction becomes a real nuisance.

Comment: `I have not seen a similarly flexible way to define a callback in any other language yet (though I'd be very interested to hear about them!)`  What you just describes sounds exactly like the way event-driven UI code works in Delphi. (And in .NET WinForms, which was heavily influenced by Delphi.)

Comment: "In C++ you cannot write down the type of a VLA" [...] -- in C++, C99-style VLAs are unnecessary, because we have `std::vector`. While it's a little less efficient due to not using stack allocation, it is functionally isomorphic to a VLA, so doesn't really count as a "blub" type issue: C++ programmers can look at how it works and just say, "ah yes, C does that more efficiently than C++".

Comment: "In C++ you cannot write down the type of a lambda. You can't even typedef it. Thus, there is no way to pass around a lambda, or store a reference to it in an object" -- that's what `std::function` is for.

Comment: "I have not seen a similarly flexible way to define a callback in any other language yet (though I'd be very interested to hear about them!). " -- in Java, you can write `object::method` and it will be converted into an instance of whatever interface the receiving code expects. C# has delegates. Every object-functional language has this feature because it's basically the point of cross-section of the two paradigms.

Comment: @Jules Your arguments are precisely what the Blub-Paradox is about: As a proficient C++ programmer, you don't see these as limitations. However, they are limitations, and other languages like C99 are more powerful in these specific points. To your last point: There are workarounds possible in many languages, but I don't know one that really allows you to pass the name of any method to some other class and have it call it on some object that you provide as well.

Comment: @cmaster C++ let's you construct a `std::function<Ret(ClassT)>` from `&ClassT::Member`, i.e. the name of a member function, similarly Java's `ClassT::Member`, similarly C#'s `o -> o.Member()`

Comment: @Caleth Now you got me curious: You mean, it's possible to pass both an object pointer and a pointer to one of its members to a dynamically linked library function, and have that library function call the object's member function correctly **without knowing the object's type?** I would have thought that you need to encapsulate both object and member function pointer into a closure that is passed via `std::function<>` to achieve type deletion. More precisely: What argument types would the library function need to accept to allow passing an arbitrary member function of an arbitrary object?

Comment: @cmaster among others `void *`, and `std::function<Ret(void*)>`, aided by a wrapper like `template<class ClassT> std::function<Ret(void*)> make_erased(Ret(ClassT::*member)()) { return [member](void * ptr){ return (static_cast<ClassT>(ptr).*member)(); }; }`. You still need to co-ordinate that object of the correct type are used, so it's often easier to expose it as a template

Comment: @Caleth Ah, ok, so basically the type-deleted closure idea. Nevertheless, why not just include the object pointer in the closure? Like `template<class ClassT> std::function<Ret()> make_erased(ClassT* o, Ret(ClassT::*member)()) { return [o, member](){ return (o->*member)(); }; }` This should work perfectly in C++, and is probably the most fitting solution in most cases. Frankly, I didn't grasp the intended use of `std::function<>` when I wrote this answer 3 years ago, it's what makes this kind of parameter passing possible. Nevertheless, Objective-C doesn't require such complex incantations...

Comment: @cmaster I was assuming the object(s) and the member(s) to call were passed to the library at different times

Comment: @Caleth While it's possible in Objective-C to pass object(s) and selector(s) at different times, the usual usecase was to pass them together. A button's action, for instance, could be set with a single call that passed both object and selector. The only exception to this that I am aware of was the generic array type that included a member function that took only a selector and invoked it on all the objects stored in the array - an operation that was used rather sparingly, and is rather questionable IMHO. That's why I think that the bundled object and member approach is a better C++ equivalent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93001/discussion-between-caleth-and-cmaster).